# Discord.js check for member getting a role

Tags: discord.js

I am currently trying to find a way to execute some code whenever a user is granted a specific role

However sadly I havent found any good resources on it

I imagine there could be a way of using the AUDIT log ,however Id like to avoid using the audit log due to security concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', async(before, after) => {
  const role = before.guild.roles.cache.get('ROLE_ID');
  if(!before.roles.has(role) && after.roles.has(role)){
    //code
  }
})
```

Pretty simple, `guildMemberUpdate` event is fired on a guild member update, ie a role update.
[#guildMemberUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate)